# Htaccess Query String Conflicts

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would lile to rewrite urls by passing **domain, sub-domain and request uri** to a php file by a query string with the following .htaccess

```
# Apache configuration

    Options -Indexes
    Options -Multiviews
    Options +FollowSymLinks


# Rewrite engine configuration

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /


# Sub domain redirection (301 redirect)

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+\.[^\.0-9]+)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]


# Request redirection

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.[^\.0-9]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?app=%2&sub=%1&req=$1 [QSA,END]
```

Here are some working examples :

```
http://dev.testdomain.tld/hello/world

=> /index.php?app=testdomain&sub=dev&req=/hello/world
```

And

```
http://www.example.tld/?var=test

=> /index.php?app=example&sub=www&req=/&var=test
```

But if i have something like this :

```
http://dev.testdomain.tld/hello/world?app=FAIL&sub=FAIL&req=FAIL

=> /index.php?app=testdomain&sub=dev&req=/hello/world&app=FAIL&sub=FAIL&req=FAIL
```

The query string will replace **domain, sub-domain and request uri** variables with `FAIL` (or everything else from url query string).
I could desactivate `[QSA]` flag, but i would like to keep the original query string, and prevent `app, sub, req` variables rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the app, sub and req parameters from your query string and use the PHP `$_SERVER` var. This PHP superglobal contains some interesting values to solve your problem:

```
http://dev.testdomain.tld/hello/world?app=FAIL&sub=FAIL&req=FAIL

var_dump($_SERVER);
```

Will lead to the following output:

```
array(...) {
  ["HTTP_HOST"]=>
  string(13) "test.test.tld"
  ["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(9) "hahah=w12"
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(28) "/~stejanse/tst.php?hahah=w12"
}
```

You could use these variables to retrieve your information instead of using mod_rewrite.